# Are you allowed to take three moves with a seven?

Tags: sorry

A player rolls a seven, moves one pawn five and then one pawn one. Are they allowed to moved the first pawn the remaining one after taking a slide?

Answer (score 5):

No, when you split the 7, you aren't allowed to split it into a 5 and a 1; you have to split it in a way that adds to a total of 7. So if you moved one pawn 5 spaces, landing on a slide, then the other pawn must be moved 2, not 1.